How can I derive equation 2.23(Newton-Raphson for Entropy) in NASA CEA analysis
It might sound a bit basic, but, I'd like to follow NASA CEA report I. analysis from the beginning.
So, I have to derive the Newton-Raphson equation from the entropy equation, which is one of the several N-R equations to build.
However, as a result of deriving the equation, we obtained a result where the terms that should be present are missing, and terms that should not be present appear.
The equation (2.23) we should have obtained is as follows:
$$\sum_{j=1}^{NG} \frac{n_j S_j}{R} \Delta \ln {n_j} + \sum_{j=NG+1}^{NS} \frac{S_j^0}{R} \Delta n_j + \left( \sum_{j=1}^{NS} \frac{n_j C_{p,j}^0}{R} \right) \Delta \ln T = \frac{s_0 - s}{R} + n - \sum_{j=1}^{NG} n_j$$
Here is my trial...
From equation (2.15a) and (2.16)
$$ f = \sum_{j=1}^{NS} \frac{n_j S_j}{R} - \frac{s_0}{R} = 0$$
The given correction variables are $\ln n_j (j=1,...,NG)$, $n_j (j=NG+1,...,NS)$, $\ln n$, $\pi_i = -\lambda / RT$ and $\ln T$.
And the definition of entropy is as equation (2.17)
$$
S_j =
\begin{cases}
S_j^0 + R \ln \frac{n_j}{n} - R \ln P  & \text{(j = 1, ... ,NG)} \\
\\\\
S_j^0   & \text{(j = NG+1, ... ,NS)}
\end{cases}
$$
To obtain the Jacobian, differentiate  f with respect to each variable,

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial \ln n_j} = \frac{\partial }{\partial \ln n_j} \left[ \sum_{j=1}^{NG} \frac{n_j S_j}{R} - \frac{s_0}{R}\right] = \sum_{j=1}^{NG} \frac{n_j S_j}{R}$$

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial n_j} = \frac{\partial }{\partial n_j} \left[ \sum_{j=NG+1}^{NS} \frac{n_j S_j^0}{R} - \frac{s_0}{R}\right] = \sum_{j=NG+1}^{NS} \frac{S_j^0}{R}$$

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial \ln n} = \frac{\partial }{\partial \ln n} \left[ \sum_{j=1}^{NG} \frac{n_j}{R} \left( S_j^0 - R \ln n_j + R \ln n - R \ln P \right) + \sum_{j=NG+1}^{NS} \frac{n_j S_j^0}{R} - \frac{s_0}{R} \right] = \sum_{j=1}^{NG} n_j$$

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial \pi_i} = 0$$

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial \ln T} = \frac{\partial}{\partial \ln T} \left[ \sum_{j=1}^{NS} \frac{n_j S_j^0}{R} - \sum_{j=1}^{NG} \frac{n_j}{R} \left( R \ln \frac{n_j}{n} - R \ln P \right) - \frac{s_0}{R}\right]$$
from the relation of $mu_j^0 = H_j^0 - T S_j^0 = T C_{p,j}^0 - T S_j^0$


$$ = \frac{\partial}{\partial \ln T} \left[ \sum_{j=1}^{NS} \frac{n_j}{R} \left( 
 C_{p,j}^0 - \frac{\mu_j^0}{T}\right) \right] = \sum_{j=1}^{NS} \frac{n_j \mu_j^0}{RT} = \sum_{j=1}^{NS} \frac{n_j C_{p,j}^0}{R} - \sum_{j=1}^{NS} \frac{n_j S_j^0}{R}$$
From the above results, the Jacobian becomes as below,
$$J = \left( \sum_{j=1}^{NG} \frac{n_j S_j}{R} \quad \sum_{j=NG+1}^{NS} \frac{S_j^0}{R} \quad \sum_{j=1}^{NG} n_j \quad  0 \quad \sum_{j=1}^{NS} \frac{n_j C_{p,j}^0}{R} - \sum_{j=1}^{NS} \frac{n_j S_j^0}{R}\right)$$
And $$\Delta x$$ becomes
$$\Delta x = \left(
\begin{matrix}
\Delta \ln n_j \\\\
\Delta n_j \\\\
\Delta \ln n \\\\
\pi_i \\\\
\Delta \ln T
\end{matrix}
\right)
$$
From $J \Delta x = -f$,
$$\sum_{j=1}^{NG} \frac{n_j S_j}{R} \Delta \ln {n_j} + \sum_{j=NG+1}^{NS} \frac{S_j^0}{R} \Delta n_j + \sum_{j=1}^{NG}n_j \Delta \ln n + \left( \sum_{j=1}^{NS} \frac{n_j C_{p,j}^0}{R} \right) \Delta \ln T - \left( \sum_{j=1}^{NS} \frac{n_j S_j^0}{R} \Delta \ln T \right)= \frac{s_0 - s}{R}$$
Here, the 3rd, and 5th terms in the left hand side are not shown in equation 2.23 and 2 terms are missing in the right hand side.
From here, I got stuck. Could there have been an error in my solution process?
Thank you in advance.
